# Problem with adding with ++ operator, what can I do?

Tags: c#, winforms

So, I as trying to create an "Open world exploration" game in C# WinForms, And while coding the mining, (which works just fine), I encountered a problem with saving the number of broken blocks to the inventory (a label). Basically, for every block player breaks, it gets added to the inventory as `inventoryWrite.Text = $"Grass: {grassHolder}, Rock: {rockHolder}";`.
Now, the thing is, sometimes, even though I use the `++` operator, it adds up to *4* to the inventory. I'm citing the code below.

```
private void Remove(object sender, EventArgs e, PictureBox itm)
        {
            if (itm.BorderStyle == BorderStyle.FixedSingle)
            {
                if (itm.Tag.Equals("grass") && items.Contains(itm))
                {
                    grassHolder++;
                    itm.Tag = "";
                }
                if (itm.Tag.Equals("rock") && items.Contains(itm))
                {
                    rockHolder++;
                    itm.Tag = "";
                }
                if (itm.Tag.Equals("dio") && items.Contains(itm))
                {
                    dioHolder++;
                    itm.Tag = "";
                }
                this.Controls.Remove(itm);
                items.Remove(itm);      
            }
        }
```

I update the inventory in a public loop, don't worry about that (interval is 1ms). But I don't think that's the problem, since I tried putting it in the `Remove()` function, and nothing seemed to change.
I've even double locked the `if` statement, but nothing! It still adds more than 1. Can anybody tell me how to solve this? Thank you a lot.

### EDIT:

As a reply to Ronald's comment, the if statement is called ONLY when the block is selected. ONLY once when the method is called.

Comment: The problem is probably not with the ++ operator, but you code is probably executed 4 times. You probably have the event subscribed multiple time

Comment: But how come it's executed 4 times since I've used two conditions in the if statement that turn false when it's executed once?

Comment: @EmmanuelGiouvanopoulos can you test how often your if-statement is being hit?

Comment: I would suggest trying to separate your game logic from your UI code. That should let you write unit tests for things like this, and make your UI code as simple as possible, since the UI is more difficult to unit test.

Comment: As a reply to Ronald's comment, the if statement is called ONLY when the block is selected. ONLY once when the method is called. As for Jonas, you need to know that this is winforms, not unity. It's gonna be more complex to store values from game Logic to use them in a separate file for UI.

Comment: @EmmanuelGiouvanopoulos the advice to separate UI and game logic would be sound advice *no matter what technologies/frameworks you're using to implement the game in*.

Comment: Have you tried debugging this?  The Visual Studio debugger is a marvelous tool for things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many points to cover in a comment and so I've had to enter an answer.

In itself the `++` operator is not the issue and will always behave as it should, but as someone reviewing a small piece of code the following points crop up.

1. `grassHolder`, `rockHolder`, `dioHolder` appear to have
   accessibility beyond this function and so could be altered
   elsewhere.
2. Function `void Remove(object sender, EventArgs e, PictureBox itm)` appears to be an event handler and yet there is no locking mechanism to ensure that the externally accessible parameters are not changed or used elsewhere whilst the function code is executed. Specifically `items` which is appears to be a collection of sorts and is used both in logic to determine whether parameters in (1) are incremented, but also has its contents changed within the function.
3. From comments made it would appear that this logic is run in
   response to user interaction, maybe by use of a mouse button or key
   event. Is this base event de-bounced to ensure that multiple
   triggers aren't handled?
4. Your statement "***saving the number of broken blocks to the inventory (a label).***"  Implies that you are storing game data within the UI. This should be avoided as it ties game data directly to the UI implementation and therefore makes it difficult to alter the game, but also ties any handling of game data directly to the UI thread.

Recommended actions:

1. Ensure that the parameters in question are not accessed and altered
   elsewhere causing the issue seen.
2. Utilize a `lock(x)` statement to ensure that `items` is not changed
   whilst this function is being executed. More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock)
3. De-bounce the mouse button or key click that triggers this function
   to ensure that multiple events aren't triggered. This is performed
   by placing a minimum time between event triggers. A minimum time
   period of say 150ms would be a good starting point. This would equate to a reasonably quick, conscious user action, but be slower than multiple events triggered by partial/poor switch contact. Incidentally this is especially true on touch screen interfaces.
4. Consider controlling access to global parameters through use of
   access functions. For example
   `int IncrementRockHolder(){ rockHolder++;}` Although implementation may appear onerous, they can greatly help with debugging as call stack information is then available showing what code is calling the function and thus making the change.
5. Implement a game engine class to control access to game data and implement game logic. This
   would allow you to unit test game functionality whilst also freeing
   it from UI implementation and restrictions.

Comment: Additional recommendation to add to the list: Create a data model, and don't store game information in UI elements such as text boxes and labels. Have the game logic handle the work needed, and the UI should only reflect the values from the data model.

Comment: Re: _"yet there is no locking mechanism to ensure that the externally accessible parameters are not changed or used elsewhere whilst the function code is executed."_  This is WinForms and this is event handler code (I'm assuming, that signature is odd).  Any code related to the form is only used in one thread; there's no need for synchronization.  If `items` is a Form member, there's no need for a lock

Comment: Thank you really much! This explanation was amazing! I'm not a good programmer, so your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Flydog57 items is an array holding all blocks. I used a foreach loop to handle collision since I gave the blocks random x coordinates.